# Serialized file size of 6.98 GB (7493681080 bytes) exceeds maximum. Подгрузка чанков в райнтайме по надобности

Tags: c#, unity3d, type-error

```
Serialized file size of 6.98 GB (7493681080 bytes) exceeds maximum. File name: 'D:/Unity/satelite_1.0.0.git/satelite/Temp/StagingArea/Data/sharedassets0.assets'. Serialized files over 4.00 GB (4294967295 bytes) cannot be loaded by the player. Some likely ways to reduce this are utilizing asset bundles, re-balancing asset locations, or limiting their serialized size e.g. limiting the maximum textur
```

Возникает из-за размера террейна(он разбит на 100 частей). Во время сборки проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне можно подгружать террайны относительно нахождения камеры? Возможно, не смотря на ограничения Unity использовать все террайны . Сейчас приходиться удалять со цены плитки террайна, что не очень хорошо . У меня есть возможность переключиться в режим беспилотника и малое количество террайнов сказывается на режиме беспилотника . Постоянно виден край карты.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Любы полезные ссылки или примеры кода подгрузки чанков в райнтайме по надобности очень будут кстати. Если у кого есть чем поделиться напиши те в ответе. Думаю с такой проблемой могут столкнуться многие, кто делает большие карты.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что вам реально нужно одним объектом хранить 7 гигабайт информации?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Мне надо подгружать большие пространства. Не обязательно хранить 7 Гбайт одним объектом. Я пишу полгода на C# в Unity и пока не сталкивался с проблемой больших карт, интересно как эффективно решают проблему более опытные программисты

Comment: @RiotBr3aker И эта проблема возникает только когда у меня в один объект вложенно такое количество террайнов ? Если я разобью на несколько родительских объектов, по 10 плиток террайна . Ошибка не будет возникать в Unity? Я почему то думал 4 Гига это вся сцена должна столько весить

Comment: Подумайте над масштабом. Если вы уменьшите размеры моделей, то может и хватить 1 террейна. Террей сам по себе очень не оптимален, а ассет размером в 6гб не будет на большей части пк, не говоря о других платформах.

Comment: @vmchar размер точно подобран по реальным размерам техники . Размером моделей не хочется менять чтоб потом опять подбирать. Я ищу способ по мере надобности подгружать нужные плитки террайна

Comment: 1 "плитка" (обычно это называют чанком) == 1 префаб, подгружайте эти префабы в рантайме по надобности, не нужно хранить все чанки под одним предком. Полученная ошибка относится именно к префабу, а не к сцене, чисто теоретически юнити поддерживает столько оперативной памяти, сколько может предоставить ОС конкретной машины.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Есть пример как это делается ? (префаб подгружается  в рантайме по надобности) Может ссылка на ассет юнити или пример кода ?

Comment: Боюсь, что нет, примеров таких нет, по крайней мере я о таком не слышал.

Comment: Теоритически чанки можно разместить на отдельных сценах. А вот сцены легко загрузить асинхронно **SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync**

Comment: Размер моделей можно в настройках импорта указать в процентах. И тогда подбирать технику друг к другу уже не надо будет. А вот 7 гб для сцены это в любом случае беда. Хотя в вашем случае уменьшив все можно обойтись гораздо меньшим размером.

Comment: @vmchar Мне не желательно указывать в процентах размер моделей. Это не вариант. Размеры моделей должны один в один совпадать с реальными. Может кто указать полезные ссылки или привести код подгрузки префабов в райнтайме по надобности? Любые полезные ссылки на ассеты или код.

Comment: @Александр Даниловский У меня на название сцен завязаны скрипты движения. Их надо будет переделывать. Не хочется плодить сцены. Подгружать префабы террайна разве менее удобно ?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov вы кажется не совсем осознаете понятие "размера" в юнити. Он же фактически никак не коррелирует с реальным миром и указывая все размеры в процентах от исходных моделей ваш "размерный реализм" никак не пострадает. А вот 7 гб террейна - действительно не вариант. В некоторых проектах, в угоду оптимальности вообще делают местность через mesh, а не террейн, потому что последний далеко не самое удачное решение

Comment: @vmchar У меня настроен импорт с карт панаромы и специалист который делает модели уже привык к определённым размерам модели. Я так понимаю вы предлагаете уменьшать модели и местность. Но как это скажется на модуле который грузит местность с понорамы не известно. Возможно прийдётся его переделывать и добавлять дополнительные параметры. Думаю такой вариант повлечёт большие изменения в проекте который сейчас пишется. Если честно я не думаю что это будет более простым решением.

Comment: @vmchar + у меня могут быть различные пространства, в том числе и очень огромные . В вашем варианте надо будет постоянно уменьшать террейны и модели, если они превышают 4 Гига?

Comment: Подгружать сцены и префабы одинаково удобно. Преимущество сцен в том, что вы их можете иметь хоть 1000 и при этом всегда будете иметь возможность редактировать конкретные сцены в редакторе, а не вручную добавлять на "основную" сцену нужный префаб.

Comment: А то, что у вас на названии сцены завязана целая система - это признак очень плохого дизайна, так быть не должно.

Comment: @vmchar не совсем понимаю, а как масштаб меши повлияет на ее конечный размер? Это все те же координаты и данные прост помноженные на коэффициент масштаба, откуда прирост по памяти?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker на сцене завязано положение камеры, сценарий камеры . Начнется или нет обстрел и ещё пару моментов

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101559/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-riotbr3aker).